# IE CSS padding-left is only padding first line of text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am going through my style sheets in an attempt to make my CSS for IE friendly and I am running into an issue with my padding-left for some reason. It is only applying the padding to the first line of text in my 'span' tag. When the text runs to the next line it goes all the way to the left inside the 'span' element.

*(Can't show screenshot for NDA purposes)*

BROWSER: IE7

CSS:

```
#rightContent .rightNav a,#rightContent .rightNav a:visited{
  color:black;
  display:block;
  width:92px;
  padding-right:12px;
  height:35px;
  background:url("../images/nav_off.png");
}
#rightContent .rightNav span{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:28px;
  padding-left:13px;
  font-size:9px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="">
    <span>This text is too long.</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can't you apply padding on <a>? Or display <span> as blocks?

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does not support `display: table-cell`: http://caniuse.com/css-table

You'll have to find an alternative technique, if only for IE7.

Try adding `*float: left` to the `span` - it will [only apply](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#css-hacks) to IE7 and lower. Maybe that will be a "good enough" fix.

It looks like you're using `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` for vertical centering. If it's *absolutely vital* to have that in IE7, it is possible without resorting to JavaScript, but it's a pain in the ass.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `display: table-cell` part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar to the question asked here: [Why Doesn't IE7 recognize my css padding styles on anchor tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330357/why-doesnt-ie7-recognize-my-css-padding-styles-on-anchor-tags) I'm not sure exactly why it does that, it seems to be an IE bug. I would suggest either wrapping your text in something else(a `div` or a `p` tag), or just putting the text straight in the `a` tag and if you need specific styles for it just give the `a` tag a class.